# Using variable inside setUpClass (class method) - unittest python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I would like to use a variable which I initialize in the subclass to be used in the setUpClass of parent class , here is the code snippet below:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(cls, arg):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(cls, arg)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print "Base.setUp()" ,cls.param

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print "Base.tearDown()"


class TestSomething(BaseTest):
    def __init__(cls, arg):
        BaseTest.__init__(cls, arg)
        cls.param = 'hello'

    def test_silly(self):
        print "Test method"
        self.assertTrue(1+1 == 2)

    def test_silly1(self):
        print "Test method"
        self.assertTrue(1+1 == 2)
```

It gives me this : `AttributeError: type object 'TestSomething' has no attribute 'param'` , which I understand is true as `setUpClass and tearDownClass` are class and not instance method, any way to use variable instantiated in the base class to be used in `setUpClass of parent class`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `cls.param` *before* you call `BaseTest.__init__(cls, arg)`.

Comment: ```print "Base.setUp()" ,cls.param
AttributeError: type object 'TestSomething' has no attribute 'param'``` Even after declaring it before the super call.

Comment: It sounds like `setUpClass` is being called before any instance of the class is created. You'd have to provide details about the test runner you are using.